# Apache mod_rewrite SSL vs Non-SSL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

I have my site setup with two conf files (one for SSL and one for Non-SSL )    The two confs are at this gist -> https://gist.github.com/akinsgre/9645179

The Non-SSL configuration works fine.  When the URL contains *autodiscover.xml*, Apache returns a 404

However, the rule appears to be ignored when the request is via SSL. I'm not getting anything meaningful in my *error.log*, or *rewrite.log* either (In fact, I'm not getting anything in rewrite.log).

Can anyone help me understand why this might not be working?

Answer (score 1):

It came down to the ssl .conf file being in the location that should have had a soft link to the file that I was editing.

As soon as I fixed the link, the redirect start working.

However, the logging wasn't working because I hadn't specified the RewriteLogLevel.  I"m not sure if the level has to be specified, or if the default is 0 and as a result nothing was being logged.